# How do I sign in a user for an integration test using only twitter authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I want to create an integration test for my app to test project#create and other stuff. The only issue is i've only created integration tests for apps that I build my own authentication. If i'm using twitter authentication only, how do I sign in a user for the integration test?

Comment: What tool you are using for the integration test?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stub out every call needed to authenticate. This includes `get_access_token` and instances of `OAuth::Consumer`. It will be 10-20 LOC, but it's not difficult. Just pull your network cable and start stubbing the network calls.